# How do I create and assignment with the Google Classroom API without a dueTime?

Tags: google-classroom

I am integrating the Google Classroom platform into our SIS and would prefer not to have to have an assignment dueTime - just a dueDate. I am aware of how to create the assignment otherwise and it is not required when creating the assignment with Google Classroom, but the API requires it. The NULL values return 12AM (once I factor in UTC).  Is it possible to not submit dueTime?  Thanks!

```
$service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
$post_body = new Google_Service_Classroom_CourseWork(array(
    "description" => 'description here...',
    "workType" => "ASSIGNMENT",
    "title" => 'title here...',
    "state" => "PUBLISHED",
    "maxPoints" => 'points here...',
    "dueDate" => array(
            "day" => 30,
            "month" => 07,
            "year" => 2020
        ),
    "dueTime" => array(
            "hours" => NULL,
            "minutes" => NULL
        )
    )
);
$params = array();
$result = $service->courses_courseWork->create($g_class_id,$post_body,$params);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Currently the situation is a described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#CourseWork):

[image]

So you **cannot** set the `dueDate` without the `dueTime`

There is already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760735) asking to implement independent setting - you can give it a "star" to icnrease visibility and hope for sooner implementation.

### However, be aware of the fact that when you

- create an assignment from the UI without specifying the time as done here:

[image]

- subsequently retrieve the assignment programmatically with [courses.courseWork.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) (or `courses.courseWork.get`)
- you will see that the system assigned a `dueTime` to the assignment:

[image]

**So, even if you do not specify a `dueTime` Google Classroom will still create one.**